# C++, multimap: функция insert не заносит новые значения с тем же ключом

Tags: c++, qtcreator, map

Я считываю информацию с файла. Ключом в контейнере (т.е. first) является первая буква считываемого слова.

```
typedef std::multimap<int, int> info;
std::map<char, info> text_info;

// ...

std::multimap<int, int> buff;
fin >> line_buffer;

while (!fin.eof())
    {
        // [даю значения переменным pos, length, first_letter]
        // ...

        buff.insert(std::make_pair(pos, length)); // эта строчка работает
        text_info.insert(std::make_pair(first_letter, buff));
        buff.clear();
        fin >> line_buffer;
    }
```

Допустим, у меня в файле подряд идут:

```
can
call
cop
```

В отладчике видно, как в **buff** вносится информация о "can", всё ок, он влезает в контейнер "text_info":

```
first -> 'c'
second -> [0] 3 3
```

Но как только я попытаюсь внести новый **buff** с буквой 'с' в начале, хоть и слово уже другое, отладчик покажет тот же результат что выше. Хотя предполагалось, что должно быть нечто подобное:

```
first -> 'c'
second -> [0] 3 3
          [1] 9 4
```

Я пересмотрел кучу примеров с использованием этой функции, но там везде просто пишут insert и всё. В то время как мой multimap отказывается делать то же самое.
Что я сделал неправильно? Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем коде делается вставка в `std::map` по имени `text_info`. И именно `text_info` вы разглядываете в отладчике. Это `std::map`, а не `std::multimap`. Если в `text_info` уже есть вставляемый ключ, то ничего вставляться не будет. Именно это вы и наблюдаете: попытка второй раз вставить в `text_info` элемент с `first -> 'c'` игнорируется. Как и должно быть.

Судя по вашему описанию, вы ожидаете, что `std::map` будет неким образом "объединять" данные в элементах с одинаковыми ключами. Почему вы этого ожидаете - не ясно, ибо ничего подобного `std::map` делать не будет.

Пока что `multimap` тут вообще ни при чем.

P.S. Цикл с предусловием `while (!fin.eof())` - практически всегда ошибка. В стандартном вводе-выводе не должно быть проверок признака `EOF`.